# passing functions address to the function pointer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I need to pass a address of the function to a function pointer.Below is the code what i'm 
trying to accomplish it.I'm sure that i'm mistaking somewhere so that i'm getting a
 runtime exception.How to pass the address of a function to a function pointer.Am i 
 missing something in this code.

### RS232Msg.h

```
typedef RS232Msg* (*tpNewMsg)(void);
typedef struct
{
    int         nMessageId;         
    NSString*   szAsciiName;        
    tpNewMsg    pNewMessageFunc;   
} stRs232Struct;   
@interface RS232Msg : NSObject
{
}
@end
```

### RS232Msg.m

```
@implementation RS232Msg
-(id)initWithRS232Msg:(int)uMessageId withNewMsg:(tpNewMsg)pNewMsg withAsciiName:(const char*)szAsciiName withData:(void*)pData withSize:(size_t)uDataSize
{
 //stmts;
}
@end
```

### RS232Derived.h

```
@interface RS232MsgRequestSession : RS232Msg{
}

+(RS232Msg*)NewMsg;
```

### RS232Derived.m

```
@implementation RS232MsgRequestSession
+(id)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg           
{                                                       
    pMsg = [RS232MsgRequestSession alloc];  
    return pMsg;
}             
-(id)init
{   
    if (self = [super initWithRS232Msg:[RS232MsgRequestSession getID] withNewMsg:[RS232MsgRequestSession NewMsg] withAsciiName:NULL withData:&st withSize:sizeof(st)]) {

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

A run time exception happens when i tried to pass the address of the function

```
withNewMsg:
[RS232MsgRequestSession NewMsg]
```

to the function pointer pNewMsg() in the initWithRS232Msg 
method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[RS232MsgRequestSession NewMsg]` doesn't get you the address of the method. The expression is evaluated and the result object is passed as the argument. While there is a way to access the implementation of a method directly (read [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/02/imp-of-current-method.html) for details), there might be an easier way to achieve what you want.

**Selector based approach**

Instead of what you're doing right now, you can consider doing something like this,

```
- (id) initWithTarget:(id)aTarget action:(SEL)aSelector ... {
    // save these two for later reference.
}
```

and later,

```
if ( [target respondsToSelector:theSelector] ) {
    result = [target performSelector:theSelector];
}
```

This way you can achieve what you want.

**Blocks based approach**

Truth be told, Blocks are turning out to be the best addition to Objective-C.

Change the typedef to `typedef RS232Msg* (^tpNewMsg)(void);`

Now the init method would become,

```
-(id)init
{   
    self = [super initWithR232Msg:[RS232MsgRequestSession getID]
                       withNewMsg:^{
                           return [RS232MsgRequestSession NewMsg];
                       }
                    withAsciiName:NULL
                         withData:&st
                         withSize:sizeof(st)]
    if ( self ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot deepak.I was breaking my head for a week of how to do pass a function as an argument to the function pointer.Thanks for explaining about it well.